# BigQuery - unable to submit queries via batch API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Our application batches queries and submits via BigQuery's batch API. We've submitted several batches of queries whose jobs have been stuck in a "running" state for over an hour now. All systems are green according to [status.cloud.google.com](http://status.cloud.google.com) but that does not appear to be the case for us.

Anyone else experiencing similar behavior? FWIW - query submission via the BQ web UI is no longer working for us either due to exceeding concurrent rate limits (from aforementioned stuck jobs), so something is woefully wrong...

Comment: Please provide a project_id:job_id of a job stuck in this state so we can investigate. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Michael - I do not have a job id, would the project ID suffice?Project ID is: dev-10450-26

Comment: I was able to pull a Job ID via the API explorer: dev-10450-26:job_Ms63bsBDU8wCKP1KDcyf3Td-E9E

Answer (score 3):

You are submitting your queries via the batch API just fine. It looks like you are doing this very quickly and with computationally expensive queries, so they all compete with each other and slow down.

It looks like you submitted about 200 jobs at approximately the same time on the 18th (a few times), and about 25k jobs on the 17th.

These were all submitted at interactive query priority, and almost all of them immediately failed with rate limit exceeded errors, leaving the max concurrent quota limit of about 50 queries running from each set of queries you submitted.

Spot checking a few of these queries: these are computationally expensive queries. Take a look at your query's Billing Tier (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#high-compute), which can be found in the jobs.get output here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.query.billingTier. These queries also appear to be re-computing the same (or at least very similar) intermediate join results.

When you run 50 large queries simultaneously, they will compete with each other for resources and slow down.

There are several issues you may want to look in to:

- You are submitting lots of queries at interactive query priority, which has a pretty strict [concurrent rate limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries). If you want to run many queries simultaneously, try using batch query priority. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.priority
- Your query mix looks like it can be optimized. Can you materialize some intermediate results that are common across all your queries with one join operation, and then run lots of smaller queries against those results?
- If you need to run many computationally expensive queries quickly:

  - You may want to purchase additional slots to increase your query throughput. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#slots.
  - You may want to rate limit yourself on the client side to prevent your computationally expensive queries from competing with each other. Consider running only a few queries at a time. You're overall throughput will likely be faster.
- You are using the batch insert API. This makes it very efficient to insert multiple queries with one HTTP request. I find that the HTTP connection is rarely the cause of latency with large scale data analysis, so to keep client code simple I prefer to use the regular jobs.insert API and insert jobs one at a time. (This becomes more important when you want to deal with error cases, as doing that with batched inserts is difficult.)

Comment: thanks for the response. We can likely create an intermediate join table as many of queries share a common sub-query. To this point we've not run into issues simultaneously batching 50+ queries, apparently we've found the right mix in this batch to slow things down. The thing that is leaving us puzzled though is the concurrent rate limit throttles us for up to 90 minutes in this case, preventing _any_ additional interactive queries in this project, is this due to the resource contention you mentioned?

Comment: per your advice I'm re-factoring our queries to use an intermediate results table. Unfortunately I am unable to create this table - I've tried running it in the BQ web UI w/ billing mode unlimited in interactive & batch mode w/ no success (my current attempt has been running > 10 mins).  It is a pretty simple query and I know it is valid as if I set LIMIT 1000, it completes in ~ 5 seconds. Could I possibly PM you this query for you to take a look at?

Comment: Intermediate create table still running - passed 2 hrs 25 minutes